# Recreating a partition on internal hard drive on Mojave/Catalina

Tags: hard-drive, time-machine, disk-utility, mojave, partition

I created a partition on my internal HDD of 50GB, in favour of Time Machine backup.

Unfortunately, I discovered that Time Machine requires **100GB** to backup my drive regularly.

So I went back to Disk Utility, and removed the partition I created, and tried create a new one (of 120GB size).

However, Disk Utility refuses to let me create a new partition larger than the previous one - 50GB

**How can I create such large partition?**

I also see that Disk Utility specifies a minimum size now for the container of 451GB.

[image]

How can I resolve this issue? Please help!
(I upgraded to Catalina OS, thinking it might help, but it behaves the same).

Comment: Your question is unclear: The screenshot shows an SSD (non-magnetic) while you are mentioning an HDD (magnetic). Further: a backup on an internal disk (if it is the only one) doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Hi Nir M, welcome to Ask Different. This doesn't answer your question, but an internal Time Machine partition is not a good idea. It makes you feel safe although you are not (if your disk fails, you lose data and backup) and it is redundant (macOS creates local snapshots until a Time Machine disk is available, see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204015 for more information). You might want to rethink your backup strategy...

Comment: Hi @klanomath, thanks for the response.
Does it really matter HDD or SSD really... it's storage.
Making a backup on the internal disk makes some definitely some sense.
Using Time Machine you can revert to an older configuration/state of your hard disk when something gets messed up.

Thanks anyway for your comment

Comment: @jaume thanks for your response.
As I mentioned, it makes some sense to do local backups.

I checked the linked you provided - it will not let me turn on TimeMachine without a specified internal storage partition or an external storage device.

Thanks